# VS Studio bizarre output in C++ (prime number check)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation

I have a short program consisting of a function that checks, whether a number is prime or not. However the compiler outputs `127` in VS Studio when I invoke the function for the number `3`. I want to ask why is that?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
bool isPrime(int k) {
    for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(i); i++) {
        if (k%i == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{

    cout << isPrime(3) << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here's a hint: What does `isPrime` return when the for loop completes?

Comment: Crank up the compiler warning levels. Your `isPrime()` promises to return a `bool`. Does it always do it?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that  `isPrime(4)` will return true.  Not sure if that's what you want. That `return true` statement in the middle of the for-loop does not look like it should belong there.

Comment: Also, the `for` loop termination condition is wrong. `i` will never be less that `sqrt(i)`, so the loop body will not be executed.

Comment: Also, your code is re-evaluating `sqrt(i)` on **every** iteration of the for loop.  sqrt is a slow function and will hinder the performance of your code.  Just evaluate `sqrt` once and save the result to a variable.

Comment: After checking `i%2`, you only need to check odd numbers.  i.e. `sqrt_k = sqrt(k); for (i = 3; i < sqrt_k; i+2) {...`

Comment: @selbie: Are we sure a compiler in 2018 is too stupid to do that for you?

Comment: It's high time you learnt how to debug. Until you can do that how can you hope to solve problems yourself.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - assuming the compiler recognizes that the  library function, `sqrt()` is special and has constant behavior... looking.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Using VS2017 as a reference and analyzing assembly output of code similar to OP's.  Debug build no. Release build yes. Let's skip over the part where we both debated the merits of my original comment ad nauseam, and get to that "agree to disagree" conclusion. :)

Comment: @selbie: No interest in debating anything ad nauseam and you can "agree to disagree" if you like; your own results have shown your original statement to be false.

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have alluded to, your program has undefined behaviour because `isPrime` doesn't always return from a function you said. From [the C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Because you have declared `isPrime` will return a `bool`, and you don't always return a `bool` you have undefined behaviour.

Instead, you probably want to iterate all odd numbers up to `k`, and check if `k` is divisible by the number, and if so `return false` (since it won't be a prime). Otherwise, `return true` at the end.

It might look like this:

```
bool isPrime(unsigned long k)
{
    for (auto i = 3; i * i <= k; i += 2)
        if (k % i == 0)
           return false;

    return true;
}
```

I'll leave it to you to work out what to do with `2`.